# Could I ensure the convergence by setting the min and max boundary of state variables in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I was struggling to improve the convergence performance of my model in Dymola during the last month. Now I am thinking about that If I define the min and max attributes of the state variables, like the max mass flow rate is 10000kg/s, the min mass flow rate is 0.01kg/s, during the iteration, when the results reaching to the max or min boundary, would the iteration be continued or it just stops? 
I am considering if when the iteration result reaches the boundary, the iteration would bounce back in the opposite direction,  it might ensure the convergence of my model.

I prepare to do some tests about my idea, If anyone got the same question or opinion, welcome to comment or answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting min/max for variables is unlikely to significantly improve performance in Dymola.

If min/max assertions are active for a variable the solver will reject the step with values out of bounds, and currently not try to map them back to valid values in a clever way. That may skip some computations based on the out-of-bounds values, but it is rare that it matters much - and there is also a cost of rejecting the step etc.

Comment: My test verified your view, I tried to add min/max attributes for the mass flow rate, enthalpy, and pressure in the thermo-hydraulic system, but it didn't improve the convergence performance. So I guess it is better to provide a better start value. But I am wondering that if I meet an initialization failure in my model ( Without using Homotopy), is there a method to find which initial value causes the divergence? Or I have to check every iteration variable in Dymola?

Comment: You have an option to create a partial result file in the case of an initialization failure. The result file is inconsistent (=wrong) because initialization did not complete, but it describes the state as far as it got so some variables may give you a clue.